# How to insert a random number which is not present in MySQL table?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, innodb

## Main Query

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO foldertable ( folderid )
             SELECT (
                        SELECT random_num
                        FROM (
                                SELECT FLOOR(RAND() * 4 + 1) AS random_num
                        ) AS numbers_mst_plus_1
                        WHERE random_num NOT IN (
                            0,1
                        )
                                  )";
```

### Problem

It inserts a Random number . But sometimes it simply inserting 0 .

### What I figure ?

When The below SQL returns a number which is equal to 0 or 1 , It is inserting zero .

```
SELECT random_num
                        FROM (
                                SELECT FLOOR(RAND() * 4 + 1) AS random_num
                        ) AS numbers_mst_plus_1
                        WHERE random_num NOT IN (
                            0,1
                        )
```

### What I want ?

select query to select a number Until it is unique for that column.

#### Try :-

I create a select Statement which selects 1,2,3,4,5

```
SELECT random_num
        FROM (
           SELECT 1 AS random_num
           UNION 
           SELECT 2 AS random_num
           UNION 
           SELECT 3 AS random_num
           UNION 
           SELECT 4 AS random_num
           UNION 
           SELECT 5 AS random_num
       ) AS numbers_mst_plus_1
```

Then try that to implement it in INSERT QUERY

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO foldertable ( folderid )
            SELECT (SELECT random_num FROM (SELECT 1 AS random_num UNION SELECT 2 AS random_num) AS temp_table WHERE random_num NOT IN (1) LIMIT 1
                    )
```

The above query always insert 2 to table and I am happy .
Then I thought  IF there is both 1 and 2 in `NOT IN` (Real e.g `Not in` Clause contains all the folder id which is present in Table   )

The catch is There -----

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO foldertable ( folderid )
            SELECT (SELECT random_num FROM (SELECT 1 AS random_num UNION SELECT 2 AS random_num) AS temp_table WHERE random_num NOT IN (1 , 2) LIMIT 1
                    )
            ";
```

Now It is again entering 0 into `folderid`  column

So I added an `WHERE` CLAUSE to it

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO foldertable ( folderid )
            SELECT (SELECT random_num FROM
                                        (SELECT 1 AS random_num UNION SELECT 2 AS random_num UNION SELECT 3 AS random_num )
                                        AS temp_table
                                        WHERE random_num
                                        NOT IN (
                                                SELECT folderid FROM foldertable
                                                )
                                        LIMIT 1
                    )
            WHERE ((SELECT COUNT(*) FROM foldertable) < 3)
            ";
```

So now it is not going to add an new row if all IDs are used .

But The real Pain in the ass is to write

```
           SELECT 1 AS random_num
           UNION 
           SELECT 2 AS random_num
           UNION 
           SELECT 3 AS random_num
           UNION 
           SELECT 4 AS random_num
           UNION 
           SELECT 5 AS random_num
           .... 100000000 times 
           UNION
           SELECCT 100000006 AS random_num
```

So That was not worth of Time

So here comes GOD `FOR LOOP`

```
$randomNoString = "";
    for ($i=0; $i < ($maxFolderId - $minFolderId + 1 ); $i++) { 
        if($i === 0){
            $randomNoString ="SELECT ".($minFolderId + $i) . " AS random_num" ;
        }
        else {
            $randomNoString =  $randomNoString ." UNION " . "SELECT ".($minFolderId + $i) . " AS random_num";
        }
    }

$sql = "INSERT INTO foldertable ( folderid )
        SELECT (SELECT random_num FROM
                                    ({$randomNoString})
                                    AS temp_table
                                    WHERE random_num
                                    NOT IN (
                                            SELECT folderid FROM foldertable
                                            )
                                    LIMIT 1
                )
        WHERE ((SELECT COUNT(*) FROM foldertable) < {$maxFolderCount})
        ";
```

#### What's Problem

1 . Now the folders Id are unique but not Random.
2. And my head is Saying that it's gonna create performance issue .

### What I can't do

1. Can't set `folderid` to unique .

## Another Thought If I wanted a string of 6 char. , How should I do that ?

Comment: Just out of interest - what is this random number needed for?  Would something like a uuid do? Or even just a unique serial id?

Comment: I am inserting  50000 record per user in a Table with unique id for each record . The id can be same of different users .

Comment: An auto increment column would provide a quick way of giving them all a unique id.

Comment: you are not getting I have an auto increment column but I need a random id between 100 to 50000 for each user . And my user count is also 50000 mean total row  = 50000 * (50000 - 100)

Comment: OK, so how is this random id used?

Comment: Why must the number be between 100 and 50000 specifically? It seems a bit arbitrary. I agree we need to understand the purpose of this number before we can say it your approach is sensible or you need to think again.

Comment: It is not mandatory that the number must be between 100 and 50000  , But 50000 - 100 record per user with an unique folder Id .That's it .

Comment: The random id is used to select the recor by that id and an ` user Specific TOken `

Comment: That makes no sense. Why would you need a random token? Just use the unique ID to select the row. If you want to know which user each row belongs to, just store their username next to it. It's not clear how this random token would add any value compared to that. You didn't really explain the scenario fully. P.s. If this is supposed to be just some one-time token (e.g. for activating an account or something) then you would just use a UUID, but I'm not sure that's your use case here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

regarding:

## Another Thought If I wanted a string of 6 char. , How should I do that ?

```
select concat(
    cast(char(64+floor(rand()*26+1)) as char),
    cast(char(64+floor(rand()*26+1)) as char),
    cast(char(64+floor(rand()*26+1)) as char),
    cast(char(64+floor(rand()*26+1)) as char),
    cast(char(64+floor(rand()*26+1)) as char),
    cast(char(64+floor(rand()*26+1)) as char)) as char6;
```

or, if you want a longer statement:

```
with recursive cte as ( 
   select 'A' as a
   union all 
   select CHAR(ORD(a)+1)
   from cte
   where a<'Z') 
select concat(c1.a,c2.a,c3.a,c4.a,c5.a,c6.a) as char6
from cte c1
cross join (select a from cte order by rand()*26+1 limit 1) c2
cross join (select a from cte order by rand()*26+1 limit 1) c3
cross join (select a from cte order by rand()*26+1 limit 1) c4
cross join (select a from cte order by rand()*26+1 limit 1) c5
cross join (select a from cte order by rand()*26+1 limit 1) c6
order by rand()*26+1
limit 1;
```

Comment: Would you like to explain the above query

Comment: The first query show the use of different standard MySQL functions, which are all explained on the [docs](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/functions.html), see [CAST](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/cast-functions.html#function_cast), [CHAR](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/string-functions.html#function_char), etc

Comment: I do not know what you mean when you say "If the string present allready in table"

Comment: I mean is IT definitely gonna select a random number Which is already not present in Table. Hope I am clear This Time

Comment: Which table are you talking about?  The query is creating a random string of 6 characters. Random means that is CAN select the same value as the previous one. If you really want somethin unique, you should use [UUID](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/miscellaneous-functions.html#function_uuid), because UUID is short for "Universally Unique IDentifier"

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/232118/discussion-between-mix-up-and-luuk).

Answer (score 1):

Plan A -- Hash:

Use a hashing function to create a new number.  This depends on the table already having an `AUTO_INCREMENT id`:

```
SELECT MD5(MAX(id)) FROM t
```

Pros:  simple, fast

Cons:  requires that `id`, the "number" is actually a 32-character hex string.

Plan B -- pre-built list:

1. built a table `nums` that the numbers 100..50000.
2. shuffle them into a different table:

   ```
    CREATE TABLE rand_nums
        SELECT num FROM nums ORDER BY RAND();
   ```
3. Extract a number

   ```
    SELECT num FROM rand_nums LIMIT 1;      -- get
    DELETE FROM rand_nums WHERE num = ...;  -- remove
   ```

Pros:  efficient (after setup_

Cons:  need some more complexity to handle concurent getting of numbers and efficiency in the step 3

Plan C -- other thoughts

If you back up a step, you may find that the higher level goal may be replaceable by some other technique.  And you may need to "fetch a random row" as the primative.  If so, here are some "pretty good" techniques for that:  http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/random

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar requirement trying to insert a random four digit join code for a game, but it needs to be unique. This is what I did. My example is just a select from a table named "game" with a column named "joincode".

You can repurpose this example and substitute game and joincode with your "foldertable" table and "folderid" column.

```
SELECT ifnull(
                (SELECT x.joincode
                 FROM
                   (SELECT FLOOR(RAND() * (9999-1) + 1) AS joincode) x
                 WHERE NOT EXISTS
                     (SELECT y.joincode
                      FROM game y
                      WHERE y.joincode=x.joincode)),
                (SELECT min(joincode)+1
                 FROM game x
                 WHERE joincode > 0
                   AND NOT EXISTS
                     (SELECT y.joincode
                      FROM game y
                      WHERE y.joincode=x.joincode+1))) ;
```

**Explanation:**
The first parameter of IFNULL selects a random number between 1 and 9999 that does not exist in the table already. If that random number does exist, then the second parameter of the IFNULL executes as a fallback. It falls back to the minimum number in the table (+1) where the next number does not exist. The fallback always succeeds but is not random.

Why did I do it this way? This is the only efficient method to insert a unique random number. Most of the time it will generate a random number in a sparsely populated table. Other techniques, as others have mentioned, would be looping procedures or large tables filled with numbers.

**Putting it all together:**

Change "(9999-1) + 1" and "folderid > 0" to your minimum and maximum values as necessary.

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO foldertable ( folderid ) values(
            (SELECT ifnull(
                    (SELECT x.folderid
                     FROM
                       (SELECT FLOOR(RAND() * (9999-1) + 1) AS folderid) x
                     WHERE NOT EXISTS
                         (SELECT y.folderid
                          FROM foldertable y
                          WHERE y.folderid=x.folderid)),
                    (SELECT min(folderid)+1
                     FROM foldertable x
                     WHERE folderid > 0
                       AND NOT EXISTS
                         (SELECT y.folderid
                          FROM foldertable y
                          WHERE y.folderid=x.folderid+1)))))";
```

**Testing:**

```
mysql> INSERT INTO foldertable ( folderid ) values(
    ->                 (SELECT ifnull(
    ->                         (SELECT x.folderid
    ->                          FROM
    ->                            (SELECT FLOOR(RAND() * (9999-1) + 1) AS folderid) x
    ->                          WHERE NOT EXISTS
    ->                              (SELECT y.folderid
    ->                               FROM foldertable y
    ->                               WHERE y.folderid=x.folderid)),
    ->                         (SELECT min(folderid)+1
    ->                          FROM foldertable x
    ->                          WHERE folderid > 0
    ->                            AND NOT EXISTS
    ->                              (SELECT y.folderid
    ->                               FROM foldertable y
    ->                               WHERE y.folderid=x.folderid+1)))));
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.10 sec)
mysql> INSERT INTO foldertable ( folderid ) values(
    ->                 (SELECT ifnull(
    ->                         (SELECT x.folderid
    ->                          FROM
    ->                            (SELECT FLOOR(RAND() * (9999-1) + 1) AS folderid) x
    ->                          WHERE NOT EXISTS
    ->                              (SELECT y.folderid
    ->                               FROM foldertable y
    ->                               WHERE y.folderid=x.folderid)),
    ->                         (SELECT min(folderid)+1
    ->                          FROM foldertable x
    ->                          WHERE folderid > 0
    ->                            AND NOT EXISTS
    ->                              (SELECT y.folderid
    ->                               FROM foldertable y
    ->                               WHERE y.folderid=x.folderid+1)))));
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.09 sec)
mysql> select * from foldertable;
+----------+
| folderid |
+----------+
|     6436 |
|     2552 |
+----------+
2 rows in set (0.09 sec)
```